# How to force starting of a new table to jump to new page when the table starts at the end of a page in HTML2PDF using TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf, html2pdf

I'm generating a PDF document with multiple pages using SPIPU HTML2PDF (https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf) which uses the TCPDF library.
I'm using tables to display contents in the PDF and some tables start at the end of a page with just the table header row in one page and the rest of the table contents on the new page. In such conditions, how can I force the table to start on the new page? Is there anyway I can check if a page cannot accommodate more than 1 rows of the table and then force it to start on new page? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try adding this to your CSS:

```
#your_table{
    break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```